# Ansible - how to remove an item from a list?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I'd like to remove an item from a list, based on another list.

```yaml
"my_list_one": [
  "item1",
  "item2",
  "item3"
]
```

My second list:

```yaml
"my_list_two": [
  "item3"
]
```

How do I remove 'item3' from this list, to set a new fact?
I tried using '-' and union, but this does not end in the desired end result.

```yaml
set_fact: 
  my_list_one: "{{ my_list_one | union(my_list_two) }}"
```

End goal:

```yaml
"my_list_one": [
  "item1",
  "item2"
]
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of `union`. You want the difference

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`difference`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) not `union`:

```
{{ my_list_one | difference(my_list_two) }}
```

---

An example playbook (note that you must also provide variable name to `set_fact`):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    my_list_one:
      - item1
      - item2
      - item3

    my_list_two:
      - item3

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_list_one: "{{ my_list_one | difference(my_list_two) }}"

    - debug: var=my_list_one
```

The result (excerpt):

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_list_one": [
        "item1",
        "item2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Excellent example! Thanks.

Comment: Just [difference](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/difference_filter.html) documentation link update

Answer (score 5):

[Ansible - Set Theory Filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters)

> To get the difference of 2 lists (items in 1 that don’t exist in 2):
>
> ```
> {{ list1 | difference(list2) }}
> ```

Note: Order matters, so you want `{{ my_list_one | difference(my_list_two) }}`

---

Since it's just a Jinja2 template, in pure Python, `list - list` is not defined.

```
In [1]: list1 = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: list2 = [3]

In [3]: list1 - list2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a683b4e3266d> in <module>()
----> 1 list1 - list2

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Instead, you can do list-comprehension

```
In [5]: [i for i in list1 if i not in list2]
Out[5]: [1, 2]
```